# How to exclude logging (like logback-classic) from jar published by sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, logback

My Scala project has a libraryDependency on slf4j because I use the API for logging.  I also want to see the logging output while running from sbt or IntelliJ, both for the Apps that runMain and the unit tests that testOnly from sbt.  Therefore there is also a libraryDependency on logback-classic.  However, I do not want that second dependency published because of the convention stated below.  When someone uses my published library, the transitive dependency should not be automatically brought in.  How should that be done?  I don't want to explain to the user how to manually exclude the transitive dependency, because they might be using any number of different tools.  The logback-classic should continue to be included in an assembled jar, however, if at all possible.  It doesn't seem like exclude() is the answer.

"Embedded components such as libraries or frameworks should not declare a dependency on any SLF4J binding/provider [like logback-classic] but only depend on slf4j-api. When a library declares a transitive dependency on a specific binding, that binding is imposed on the end-user negating the purpose of SLF4J. Note that declaring a non-transitive dependency on a binding, for example for testing, does not affect the end-user."

Comment: I recommend you to read [this article](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). It's for maven, but sbt is similar. `% Test`, `% Provided` dependency or `exclude` seems suitable, but you can choose way.

Comment: Hmm.  I don't think these will quite work for me.  There are Apps (i.e., object EntryPoint extends App) involved and I want people who download the project from github and run the Apps to see the logging, so Test doesn't seem adequate.  It seems like Provided means that the user of the project (as from github) would have to provide the logging library (not desired) or it could be included as an unmanaged resource, but then it would end up in the published jar (not desired).  NonTransitive would be good!  I'm thinking it might require some kind of "(dependencyClasspath) in publish <<=".

Comment: Perhaps I should modify the generated POM via pomPostProcess.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: pomPostProcess worked fine and the logback-classic can be filtered out when the POM file is built.  However, when publishLocal is used, despite the setting publishMavenStyle := true, an ivy.xml file is created.  When that locally published project is used as a dependency, then the ivy file seems to be consulted rather than the POM file, and the dependency on logback-classic returns.  That's not a showstopper, but it would be great to clean up that file as well.  Does anyone know how to edit the file ivy.xml as it is created?  So far ivySbt hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Publish the jar with `slf4j-api` but use the sbt `Test` configuration for `logback`.  Unit tests will then have a concrete implementation but it won't be packaged in your artifact.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.36",
   "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.11" % Test
 )
```

This would be a project with sub-projects. Your sample app uses a concrete implementation, but not the library. Anyone using the library would provide their own.

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    publish / skip := true,
   )
   .aggregate(sampleApp, theLibrary)

 lazy val sampleApp = project
 .settings(
   publish / skip := true,
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.11"
   )
 )
 .dependsOn(theLibrary % "test->test;compile->compile")

 lazy val theLibrary = project
   .settings(
     libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.36",
        "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.11" % Test
        )
      )
```

Comment: Thanks.  I hope to use it for more than just Test.  People download the project directly from github to run the apps and would want to see the logging.  People who reuse the project as a library will be skilled enough to add their own logging, though, and they won't want to be stuck with what I might provide.

Comment: Wouldn't your projects consist of at least two sub-projects? A library and an app? The library sub-project would do what I suggested whereas the app sub-project actually uses logback.

Comment: Thanks again.  The particular projects I'm concerned about already have half a dozen subprojects and ~50 Apps, so I don't think it's feasible to reorganize them.  For future projects, especially simpler ones, I may collect all Apps in a special subproject, like you suggest.  It's probably a good strategy.  Right now pomPostProcess is looking good, but I haven't figured out what to do with the ivys.

Comment: Do you have library and app code co-mingled in the same sub-project?s

Answer (score 0):

My tentative solution is to add this code to an sbt file

```scala
ThisBuild / pomPostProcess := {
  val logback = DependencyId("ch.qos.logback", "logback-classic")
  val rule = DependencyFilter { dependencyId =>
    dependencyId != logback
  }

  (node: Node) => new RuleTransformer(rule).transform(node).head
}
```

and back it up with this Scala code in the project directory

```scala
package org.clulab.sbt

import scala.xml.Node
import scala.xml.NodeSeq
import scala.xml.transform.RewriteRule

case class DependencyId(groupId: String, artifactId: String)

abstract class DependencyTransformer extends RewriteRule {

  override def transform(node: Node): NodeSeq = {
    val name = node.nameToString(new StringBuilder()).toString()

    name match {
      case "dependency" =>
        val groupId = (node \ "groupId").text.trim
        val artifactId = (node \ "artifactId").text.trim

        transform(node, DependencyId(groupId, artifactId))
      case _ => node
    }
  }

  def transform(node: Node, dependencyId: DependencyId): NodeSeq
}

class DependencyFilter(filter: DependencyId => Boolean) extends DependencyTransformer {

  def transform(node: Node, dependencyId: DependencyId): NodeSeq =
      if (filter(dependencyId)) node
      else Nil
}

object DependencyFilter {

  def apply(filter: DependencyId => Boolean): DependencyFilter = new DependencyFilter(filter)
}
```

I'm still hoping to find a similar solution for editing ivy.xml.